# Laurent Series of $(z-2)/(z+1)$ at $z=-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

What's the Laurent series expansion of $\frac{z-2}{z+1}$ at $z=-1$?

Comment: $z+1=(z-1)+2...$

Comment: @RickSanchez A laurent series about $z_0 = -1$ will have the form $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n (z+1)^n$ not $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n (z-1)^n$

Comment: Yes, of course, I meant $z-2=(z+1)-3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{z-2}{z+1} = \frac{(z + 1) - 3}{z+1} = 1-\frac{3}{z+1} = \frac{1}{(z+1)^0} + \frac{-3}{(z+1)^1}.$$

So $$\frac{z-2}{z+1} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n (z+1)^n$$ where $a_0 = 1$, $a_{-1} = -3$ and $a_j = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: How can I know the radius of convergence then?

Comment: The radius of convergence is the maximal distance from the center to the first singularity.

Comment: So this series converges when $z\neq -1$?

Comment: @Kenneth.K The region of convergence is the punctured disk $0 < |z+1| < \infty$.

Comment: @MathMajor Well then $|z+1|>0$ is $z\neq -1$.

Comment: @Kenneth.K Usually when we speak about Laurent series, we talk of the punctured disk $0 < |z - z_0| < R$ for some $0 < R \le \infty$. This is due to to the nature of the convergence theorems which guarantee that the Laurent series converges inside a **punctured disk** under some conditions. Similarly, when we speak about Taylor series, we typically give convergence in a disk $0 \color{red}{\le} |z - z_0| < R$ where $R$ is the *radius of convergence*.